# Is mobx-react (6.1.4) version is compatable for react 18

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Is there any issues other than [React 18: observer not working with <React.StrictMode>](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/3395)

Answer (score 0):

[Compatibility matrix](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/tree/main/packages/mobx-react#compatibility-matrix)

| MobX version | React version |
| --- | --- |
| 6.* | 16.8+ |
| 4.+/5._ | 16.8+ |

[image: compatibility matrix]

As you can see `6.*` should work with React `16.8+`